# Does an in-thread uncaught exception kill only the thread or the whole process?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

When an exception is raised inside a thread without catching it anywhere else, will it then kill the whole application/interpreter/process? Or will it only kill the thread?

Comment: Have you tried creating a thread that throws an exception?

Answer (score 12):

Let's try it:

```
import threading
import time

class ThreadWorker(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        print "Statement from a thread!"
        raise Dead


class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        print "initializing the thread"
        t = ThreadWorker()
        t.start()
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Did it work?"


class Dead(Exception): pass



Main()
```

The code above yields the following results:

> ```
> > initializing the thread 
> > Statement from a thread! 
> > Exception in thread
> > Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
> >     self.run()   File ".\pythreading.py", line 8, in run
> >     raise Dead Dead
> > ----- here the interpreter sleeps for 2 seconds -----
> > Did it work?
> ```

So, the answer to your question is that a raised Exception crashes only the thread it is in, not the whole program.

Comment: I am using concurrent thread pool. If a thread got killed a new thread will spawn in thread pool or not???

Answer (score 7):

From the [threading](http://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) documentation:

> Once the thread’s activity is started, the thread is considered
>   ‘alive’. It stops being alive when its run() method terminates –
>   either normally, or by raising an unhandled exception. The is_alive()
>   method tests whether the thread is alive.

And also:

> join(timeout=None)
>
> Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either
>   normally or through an unhandled exception –, or until the optional
>   timeout occurs.

In other words, the uncaught exception is a way to end a thread, and will be detected in the parent's `join` call on said thread.